# how to convert excel serial date number to date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I was trying to covert same Excel date format to dd/mm/yyyy format. But I am not getting the correct result.

```
43236   16-May-18
43249   29-May-18
43238   18-May-18
43228   8-May-18
43238   18-May-18
```

I am using the below query

`SELECT to_date('31-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy')+43236 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('31-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy')+43249 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('31-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy')+43238 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('31-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy')+43228 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('31-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy')+43238 FROM dual;`

I am getting the below result which is not correct

```
17-MAY-18
30-MAY-18
19-MAY-18
09-MAY-18
19-MAY-18
```

Please help me on that. I am using Oracle 11g R2.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: How is `43238` supposed to return 18-May-18 and 20-May-18 at the same time (line 3 and 5)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. I have edited the post..

Answer (score 2):

You're simply off by 1. Use *30 Dec 1899* (instead of *31 Dec 1899*) as the reference date for index 0.

```
SELECT to_date('31-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy') + 43236 FROM dual
```

The reason it's 30 Dec 1899 and not 1 Jan 1900 is twofold:

1. In Excel, 1 Jan 1900 is saved as 1 (and not as 0 as an IT guy would expect).
2. Excel treats the year 1900 has a leap year even though it wasn't. Therefore, Excel also has a number for 29 Feb 1900, which did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `TO_DATE` and set language culture then `TO_CHAR` for your expected format.

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('16-May-18','DD-Mon-YY', 'nls_date_language = american'),'DD/mm/yyyy')
from dual
```

or like this.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date('31-12-1899','dd-mm-yyyy')+43236,'DD/mm/yyyy') FROM dual
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b34b5c28dcb8d14f30df296e586f708)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using to_char() function

```
select to_char(TO_date('31-12-1899', 'dd-mm-yyyy')+43236,'DD/MM/YYYY')  from dual
```